# Better solution for PARTITION BY?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to optimize this

```
WITH a as
(SELECT *
       ,ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY applicationid ORDER BY AgreementStartDate desc) rn
       ,(select count(*) from RM_TbPackages where d.ApplicationID=ApplicationID) as PackageCount 
 FROM CM_VwSupplierApplications d)
select * from a
where rn=1
order by a.ApplicationID
```

Comment: That is a good way of doing it, ***why*** do you ant to do it differently?  What is you functional objective?  Just shorter code?  Are you happy to accept worse performance in order to get shorter code, and if so, why?  Or do you have some other objective?

Comment: A mistake beginners make is premature optimization,which sometimes is not an optimization at all.

Comment: This is a valid question.  The current query is getting counts early that are later not used.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, there is nothing wrong with the `partition`. One possible inefficiency is the subquery `(select count(*) from RM_TbPackages where d.ApplicationID=ApplicationID)` - a set based approach to this by computing all counts per Application and then joining to the count should improve performance:

```
WITH a as
(
   SELECT * , 
      ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY applicationid ORDER BY AgreementStartDate desc) rn,
      x.PackageCount
   FROM CM_VwSupplierApplications d
      INNER JOIN 
      (select ApplicationID, count(*) as PackageCount 
         from RM_TbPackages
         group by ApplicationID )x
      on x.ApplicationID = d.ApplicationID
 )
select * from a
where rn=1
order by a.ApplicationID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will run faster since it is not making a subselect for ever row in CM_VwSupplierApplications:

```
;WITH a AS
(
SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY applicationid ORDER BY AgreementStartDate desc) rn
FROM CM_VwSupplierApplications d
)
SELECT a.*, b.PackageCount
FROM a
OUTER APPLY
(  SELECT count(*) PackageCount 
   FROM RM_TbPackages 
   WHERE d.ApplicationID=ApplicationID) b
WHERE a.rn=1
ORDER BY a.ApplicationID
```

To improve it even more, you could consider index on table CM_VwSupplierApplications on the columns applicationid and AgreementStartDate